# Store HTTP_REFERER information for all site hits in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, http-referer

Most of the referrers for my website are Search Engines and I would like to store the referrer link so that I can study the keywords that lead to my page being displayed and clicked. I currently notice these links only in my Apache Error Log files when some Warning is thrown. Is there any module that I can make use so that it automatically stores all the HTTP_REFERRER links. Currently in prestashop I noticed only 404 page referrers are stored.

Comment: Hello. If answer helps you, please validate it. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prestashop already store referrer by default. Check menu Statistics -> Visitors Origin.
If you want a more detailed statistic you should install Google Analytics module.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for exact links of the referer and it is stored in '_DB_PREFIX_'connections_source table. Your answer helped me to find that table.